# I'm getting a socket closed exception, with a bluetooth connection

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

Whenever i try to write something through the socket created I get a Broken Pipe exception on the Connected thread, I followed the examples on the Android development pages (Create three diferent threads, to connect, to accept, and to receive data) but for some reason everytime i try to send something the thread is close

the class I created is the following:

```
public class BluetoothService {

private static final UUID MY_UUID =
        UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
private static final String NAME = "Guess the Movie";
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private Context context;

private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;


public BluetoothService(Context context) {
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    this.context = context;
}

private void manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
    // TODO: 25/06/2017
    Log.d(TAG, "socket received" + socket);
    connected(socket, device);
}

public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    // Update UI title
    //updateUserInterfaceTitle();
}

public synchronized void start() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mAcceptThread == null) {
        mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mAcceptThread.start();
    }
    // Update UI title
    //updateUserInterfaceTitle();
}

public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
        device) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connected() called");

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {
        mAcceptThread.cancel();
        mAcceptThread = null;
    }


    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    Log.d(TAG, "connected() finished");

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    /*
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    // Update UI title
    updateUserInterfaceTitle();
   */
}

public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    Log.d(TAG, "write() called");
    r.write(out);
    Log.d(TAG, "write() finished");
}

private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
        // because mmServerSocket is final
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                manageConnectedSocket(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish
     */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
            }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    /**
     * Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket
     */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                //mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                //        .sendToTarget();
                processarMensagem(bytes);
                Log.d(TAG, "received: " + bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            Log.d(TAG, "sent: " + bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In multiple places you catch an IOException and then silently discard it. That makes figuring out what went wrong nearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the Bluetooth socket and Outputstreem

```
public void Disconnect Socket(){
        try {
       if (DpBtOutputStream!=null)
                DpBtOutputStream.close();
        }
            if (DpBluetoothSocket!=null)

         DpBluetoothSocket.close();

        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```